# Rotate mariadb bin-relay logs

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

I have a fedora23 install with mariadb-10.0.21 that's been running for about a month, and there are a few dozen files of the form hostname-relay-bin.00005, hostname-relay-bin.00006, etc in /var/lib/mysql, with modification dates many days ago.

I thought the two /etc/my.cnf config options:

```
 relay_log_space_limit = 500M
 relay_log_purge = 1
```

would have been enough to have mariadb delete those files when they're finished, but apparently it isn't.

All the files are timestamped at the same time my mysqlbackup script is run every night. This is the command-line I use:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --complete-insert --compress --add-drop-table \
    --flush-logs --lock-tables --verbose -u root -p'pass' \
    --log-error=$basedir/backup-$dbase-$today-error.log \
    --debug-info --result-file=$basedir/backup-$dbase-$today.sql $dbase
```

Is mysqldump somehow causing mariadb to close the binary relay log and open a new one?

Answer (score 0):

`FLUSH LOGS` is done.  A new binlog is created.  No harm done.

Note that you asked for `--flush-logs`.

You can manually execute `FLUSH LOGS;` to see what happens.

[Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_flush-logs) and [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html).